# In Pokemon, is base damage done to multiple targets the same?

Tags: pokemon-series

Let's say I have a Swampert that knows Surf, and I'm in a double battle against two identical Pokemon (EV's, IV's, items, the works). If I use the move, will it deal the exact same damage to both of them or is it slightly random?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking the [damage calculation formula](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Damage#Damage_calculation), there's a random modifier applied to damage dealt by a move.

> `random` is a random factor between 0.85 and 1.00 (inclusive):
>
> - From Generation III onward, it is a random integer percentage between 0.85 and 1.00 (inclusive)
> - In Generations I and II, it is realized as a multiplication by a random uniformly distributed integer between 217 and 255 (inclusive), followed by an integer division by 255

So to answer your question, the damage calculation is performed individually against both Pokemon and it's likely that your Swampert's Surf will deal different damage to both targets.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that all "spread" moves will only deal 80% of their usual damage in a double/triple battle.

Comment: @Pyritie It's actually 75% (25% less damage) and only if there is more than one target. Surf on a single enemy in Double Battle will do its full damage (minus the aforementioned random factor of course).